# How to view process template that is being used by TFS project?

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS 2010. There are bunch of projects under DefaultCollection. I want to view the process template that was used to create individual projects. I have admin rights on the TFS server box.

How to view which project is using which process template?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you currently can't, because TFS doesn't keep track of it once the template is created.  You might be able to look at some of the workitem fields and determine what template was used from them.